# Characters not properly displayed in serial monitor in arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-ide

Can anyone tell me why the characters are not getting printed properly in the serial monitor of Arduino? I am pasting the arduino code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

    // initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins

      LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);

     int bluetoothTx = 15;
      int bluetoothRx = 14;

        SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

         int incomingByte;

         void setup() {
         pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
         Serial.begin(9600);
           lcd.begin(16, 2);
           lcd.clear();
           bluetooth.begin(115200);        // The Bluetooth Mate defaults to 115200bps
            delay(320);                     // IMPORTANT DELAY! (Minimum ~276ms)
             bluetooth.print("$$$");         // Enter command mode
             delay(15);                      // IMPORTANT DELAY! (Minimum ~10ms)
                bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");  // Temporarily Change the baudrate to    9600, no parity
                bluetooth.begin(9600);          // Start bluetooth serial at 9600

                lcd.print("done setup");

               }

                void loop()

                  {
                    lcd.clear();
                     Serial.print("in loop");
                   //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
                    if(bluetooth.available()) {
                    Serial.print("BT here");
                    char toSend = (char)bluetooth.read();
                     Serial.print(toSend);
                        lcd.print(toSend);
                       delay(3000);  
                   }delay(3000); 
         }
```

Can anyone take a look into it. It does not print the character that I provide instead it prints something else like 'y' with 2 dots on top etc. Tried almost all the available solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues could be one of a couple things. First and easiest to check is COMMON GROUND. Did you connect just the RX and TX pins or also the GND (ground) pin? Make sure that the ground from the BT mate is connected to the Arduino ground.

If you have done that, then your issue is with the baud rate. I'm pretty sure that SoftwareSerial can't read at baud rates beyond 57600. Arduino.cc docs say it can read at 115200, but other places say it will only write up to 115200.

To test this, you will either need to change the settings for this on the Bluetooth Mate or use a Mega or Leonardo which will have a hardware serial port (other than the one used for USB) which you should be able to configure for 115200.

If you try it with hardware serial either on a Mega or just using an FTDI or something and the messages still look garbled then perhaps the bluetooth mate is not actually configured to talk at 115200 as it claims. Trying reading the docs or testing with other baud rates.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether error is present due to one of the following reasons:-

**1)** You haven't given any **command to exit** from the **data mode**. After setting the baudrate to 9600, you are directly switching to loop. You haven't given the command to exit the command mode.

**2)** I too had the same problem when I was using **RN171 Wi-Fi module**. The cause of the problem in my case was because I was sending data to Wi-Fi module in **integer** format instead of **uint_8**. While reading from the Wi-Fi module serially with arduino mega, I was reading it in the format of **characters**.

You have to remember that **int** is actually **signed 16 bit integer**. So while sending data to your Bluetooth module you have to send it as **uint_8** or **ASCII** values of the characters that you want to send. You should also read it in the same format as you sent it.

**3)** If these are not the error then as **calumb** said, there can be error in setting the bluetooth module in command mode. You haven't checked for reply from bluetooth module whether it is really in command mode or not. You must read an **CMD** reply from bluetooth module and at the end of every command a reply of **ack** to conform that its really done what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of Bluetooth parsing data simultaneously. when sending two different data at the same time this may happens. try to control your data flow.